# Getting TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-analytics

I am trying to fetch the 7 days of google analytics data in my node/react js app. Currently, I am trying to show the data in chart format in react js. But whenever i am trying to pass the data in DATAPOINTS `{ dataPoints={["2","3","4","6"]}}` parameter in chart. It's giving me an error.

Note --- If i am passing the dataPoints static, it's working like a charm like this --- `dataPoints={["2","3","4","6"]}`

If I am passing the value using state, it's giving me CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object in react error.

I am a newbie in react and node js and trying to solve the issue for 6.3 hours, but still, there is no luck.

**Here is my API Route**

```
 app.get("/api/ga/sevendata",
   authJwt.check_token_auth,
    controller.sevendata
   );
```

**Controller**

```
async function getSevenDayData() {
  const response = await jwt.authorize()
  const result = await google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get({
    'auth': jwt,
    'ids': 'ga:' + view_id,
    'start-date': '7daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'yesterday',
    'dimensions': 'ga:date',
     'metrics': 'ga:users, ga:bounceRate, ga:avgSessionDuration, ga:sessions'
    
  })

  const lastSevenDayUser = [];
  result.data.rows.map(item => {
        
            var user = item[1];
          
             lastSevenDayUser.push({user : user });
          
      })

      return lastSevenDayUser;
}

//Exporting the result to the react app / frontend 
exports.sevendata = (req, res) => {

  const getpastsevendata = getSevenDayData();
   getpastsevendata.then(function(result){
        res.send(result);
        });
}
```

**React frontend area/ widget area**

```
 const [usersevenDayTime, setPastSevenTimeUser] = useState('');  //using use state

const SevenDayData= ()=> {

    const config = {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
};
const bodyParameters = {
   key: "value"
};

const changeableUrl = "http://167.172.209.57:8080/api/ga/sevendata";
    axios.get(changeableUrl,config)
.then((response) => {


  // Empty Variables here
  const user = [];

response.data.map(item => {
    
    // Pusing data in array type variable
      user.push(item.user);
      
        })

  //Setting element in use state hook 
  setPastSevenTimeUser(user); 
 

}, (error) => {
  
  console.log(error);
});

  }
```

**Here is the react chart widget code**

```
 <ChartLineSimple
              pointed
              className="c-chart-wrapper mt-3 mx-3"
              style={{height: '70px'}}
              dataPoints={["2","3","4","6"]}  //Working fine here incase of static
              pointHoverBackgroundColor="primary"
              label="Members"
              labels="months"
            />

<ChartLineSimple
              pointed
              className="c-chart-wrapper mt-3 mx-3"
              style={{height: '70px'}}
              dataPoints={usersevenDayTime}  //It's NOT Working 
              pointHoverBackgroundColor="primary"
              label="Members"
              labels="months"
            />
```

**console**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znBLU.png)

Comment: Here is an image, Where dot's are visibile. I have to set the usestate varibale in it -- http://prntscr.com/v31v4p

Comment: If you expect the state object to hold an array you should initialize it with an empty array `const [usersevenDayTime, setPastSevenTimeUser] = useState([]);` not that this will solve your problem but is good practice.

Comment: In the `response.data.map()` loop if you console.log(user) do you get the same type of data as the hardcoded dataPoints?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez , Yes i am getting the same type of data as mentioned in dataPoint

Comment: Mind sharing the log?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez Thanks a lot  , it's working like a charm const [usersevenDayTime, setPastSevenTimeUser] = useState([]);

You saved my day :)